# Angular 6 call function from 1 component to another but data not changed

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular6

I am new to Angular 6. I have `header component` and `dashboard component`.

In my `header comp` I am having notification popup with list of notifications with accept and delete options.

In my `dashboard component`, I have list of accepted notifications.

If I accept the new notification from header, the list should be updated in dashboard.

In my header component I have include the flowwing

```
import { DashboardComponent } from '../../pages/dashboard/dashboard.component';
```

// Included the dashboard component as provider

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-siteheader',
  providers:[DashboardComponent ],
  templateUrl: './siteheader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./siteheader.component.css']
})
```

// In constructor called the `dashcomp`

```
 constructor( private dashcomp: DashboardComponent, private dashboardservice: DashboardService, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }
```

// notify accept action

```
actionaccept(id){

    this.authenticationService.acceptaction(id)
            .subscribe(
                data => {  


// caled the dashboard function

                   this.loaddashboard();
                }
            );

  }
```

// by using this function called the dashboard component's function.

```
 public loaddashboard() {
        console.log('called');
        this.dashcomp.dolist('future'); 
      }
```

In Dashboard component:

```
dolist(type) {
    console.log('dasss');
     this.dashservice.listengagement(type,this.page,this.limit)
            .subscribe(
                data => {    
                  console.log(data);
                   this.futureloader = false;
                   this.futurelist = data['result']; 
                   this.futuretotal = data['count'];

                }
            );
  }
```

In dashboard html the result displayed using `ngfor`

What my issue is:: from header the dashboard function tiggered. It shows the console. But the output not changed in the dashboard. Am I missing anything??

Comment: use BehaviorSubject with Observable

Comment: You can use a behavior subject in service which is a singleton . Update it and Subscribe to it where ever you want consistent data. https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/

Answer (score 2):

You need to get an Observable of your list, and use async pipe with ngFor in html to show the list. Also the way you import dashboard component in header component is bad practice. The better way is make a service for your list handling, and inject the service in both components.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am new to angular. Do you know any working demo regard this ?

Comment: Try this. https://medium.com/dailyjs/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb

Answer (score 1):

You can use rxjs **Subject**

first create `common.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class CommonService {

  subject$ = new Subject<any>();

}
```

then from your `header.component.ts` call **next** method to set value,

```
constructor(private commonService: CommonService) { }

loaddashboard() {
    console.log('called');
    this.commonService.subject$.next('future');
  }
```

and in `dashboard.component.ts` subscribe that event

```
constructor(private commonService: CommonService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.commonService.subject$.subscribe(data =>{
      console.log('response from header is => ',data);
    });
  }
```

here's the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yn19bk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdashboard%2Fdashboard.component.ts)  demo

Comment: I have implemented the above steps. no one function is triggered in dashboard. Here where to call the dolist(type)  function.